# Prove that if $\{f = -\infty\} \in \Sigma$ and $\{ \alpha < f < \infty \} \in \Sigma$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

The question is as follows:

> Suppose $(X,\Sigma)$ is a measurable space and $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}\cup\{-\infty\}$. Prove that $f$ is measurable if and only if $\{f = -\infty\} \in \Sigma$ and $\{ \alpha < f < \infty \} \in \Sigma$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

$\Rightarrow$ is easy.

$\Leftarrow$ first I noticed that if $\{f = +\infty\} \in \Sigma$ the result follows because if that happens $\{f > \alpha \} =  \{ \alpha < f < \infty \} \cup \{f = +\infty\} \in \Sigma$ for all $\alpha$ but no matter how I try it, using complementar and anything I can't show that $\{f = +\infty\} \in \Sigma$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
(-\infty < f < \infty ) = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (-n < f <\infty ) \in \Sigma
$$
hence
$$
(f=+\infty) =((-\infty < f <\infty )\cup (f=-\infty))^c = (-\infty < f <\infty )^c \cap (f=-\infty)^c \in \Sigma.
$$